# Эвфемизмы и ненормативная лексика

Tags: обсценная-лексика

Переписывался недавно с поддержкой одной игры в социальной сети. Обсуждали использование эвфемизмов в чате.

Если судить [по Википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%B2%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC), то эвфемизимы - "нейтральное по смыслу и эмоциональной «нагрузке»", а значит замена ими матершинных слов вполне уместна.

Но саппорт с этой точкой зрения не согласен, вот его ответ:

> Здравствуйте.
>
> В Википедии написано "Эвфеми́зм (греч. ευφήμη — «благоречие») — нейтральное по смыслу и эмоциональной «нагрузке» слово или описательное выражение, обычно используемое в текстах и публичных высказываниях для замены других, считающихся неприличными или 
>   неуместными, слов и выражений." Ненормативная лексика не может быть "нейтральной" как ни крути, а следовательно эвфемизмы матерных слов можно смело приравнивать к завуалированному мату. Если сравнивать слова "блин" и прочие, то они будут вполне нейтральны и действительно можно отнести их к эвфемизмам, но слово из Вашего 
>   скриншота не является нейтральным и поэтому относится к завуалированному 
>   мату.
>
> Итого:
>
> 1. Эвфемизм - замена грубых слов на более мягкие, нейтральные аналоги, которые в сообществе уже не принимаются за ненормативную лексику.
> 2. Завуалированный мат - это замена ненормативных слов/выражений на аналогичные с целью смягчить, но суть заменяемого слова/выражения четко ясна.

Они пишут "Ненормативная лексика не может быть "нейтральной", но ведь речь идет уже не о ненормативной лексике, а о ее замене - об эвфемизме, цель которого сделать "не нейтральное" нейтральным.

Про тот же "блин" - ведь он как раз используется для замены ненормативной лексики, но при этом его они считают допустимым.

Особенно понравилось - "суть заменяемого слова/выражения четко ясна". Если я напишу что-то типа "я тобою недоволен" и "... (много матерных слов)" - то суть в обоих случаях будет одна и та же и будет ясна - так получается первое выражение мне так же нельзя использовать, т. к. таким образом я завуалировал мат? )

Так кто из нас прав? Можно ли эвфемизмы, используемые для замены ненормативной лексики, считать нейтральными?

И если верить [Википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82), то мат - это наиболее грубая разновидность ненормативной лексики. Можно ли эвфемизмы, используемые для замены мата, так же считать нейтральными?

Answer (score 3):

Это вообще не сюда вопрос. 
Отношение к табуированной лексике (в самом широком смысле) регулируется правилами этикета, а не русского языка. 
Поэтому реально отвечаю только на то, что связано с лингвистической терминологией - ну или известно по опыту.

Перво-наперво, спорить с поддержкой бесполезно, она всегда права. Хорошо еще, что удосужились донести до Вас свое понимание. Хотя, признаться, их позиция мне тоже кажется путанной и внутренне противоречивой.

Далее. Понятие эвфемизма на самом деле не предполагает какой-то оценки его нейтральности ***в контексте высказывания***, важно только, чтобы это слово само по себе было понятно, относилось к объекту и было разрешено к употреблению - это, видимо, и имеется в виду под нейтральностью в Википедии. Если в данной конкретной среде заменяющее слово тоже считается табуированным, то оно никак не может служить "нейтральным" эвфемизмом.

Тут надо еще понять, что "классический" эвфемизм это обычно обозначение понятия через какое-то его свойство, эпитет, но отнюдь не просто случайное созвучие. С такой точки зрения "трахать", например, вполне можно считать допустимым, а "блин" - нет. Хотя кто-то может счесть и наоборот - единый подход опять-таки никем и ничем не нормируется.

И еще. В историческом аспекте отнесение тех или иных слов (включая вчерашние эвфемизмы) весьма изменчиво. Не знаю, допустим ли тут подобный пример, но известная цепочка обозначений мужского полового органа от "уда" до "хера" и "хрена" весьма показательна. Кадое следующее слово в ней в какой-то момент было эфемизмом предыдущего, но постепенно само становилось полностью или частично табуированным. Зато древний славянский "уд" полностью реабилитирован.

Ну и возвращаясь к Интернет-ресурсам. Они подходят к вопросу по-разному, частенько (как, видимо, и в Вашем случае) трактуя запрет на нецензурную лексику как запрет на упоминание самого объекта за запрещенным словом стоящего, - иначе, как литературным словарным словом, этот объект обозначающим.

Не знаю, поможет ли Вам.

Comment: Разговор с поддержкой зашел из-за бана за слово "мля".

По той же википедии - "блин" служит для замены "блять", "мля" - для замены "бля". Что для меня в принципе одно и то же. Если за последнее банят, то почему тогда не банят за первое? Это я и хотел узнать у поддержки, но внятного ответа как-то не получил...

Ваш ответ, если честно, ясности не добавил) Если "понятие эвфемизма не предполагает оценки его нейтральности", то зачем тогда вообще вводится данное понятие? Ведь жаргонизм, например, при любом раскладе является жаргонизмом.

Для себя только понял, что в чате лучше ничего не писать))

Comment: >>"понятие эвфемизма не предполагает оценки его нейтральности", то зачем тогда вообще вводится данное понятие?   
  
У меня ж выделено - **в контексте высказывания**. Т.е Слово "нейтральный" (в Вики) нельзя так однобоко траковать. В другом контектсе это слово может быть нейтральным, или окрашенным, или каким еще, но разрешенным к употреблению.  
И "вводится" это понятие именно по такой причине. Слово **само по себе** разрешено к употреблению. Но в определенных контекстах может быть и запретным.  
  
Кстати, в более серьезных источниках слово нейтральный вообще отсутствует.

Comment: ЕВФЕМИЗМ, или ЭВФЕМИЗМ [греческое — «благоречие»] — замена слов, признанных грубыми или «непристойными», посредством описательных выражений, иностранных слов или бессмысленных созвучий («невыразимые» вместо «штаны», «в интересном положении» вместо «беременная», «клозет» вместо «нужник», «елки-палки» и т. п.)

http://feb-web.ru/feb/litenc/encyclop/le4/le4-0522.htm

Посмотрите, может понятнее станет. 

Хотя я сказал, это вопрос не лингвистический, а этикетный. Тут филологические подходы могут быть бессильны.

Answer (score 0):

За  блин  не  банят,  т.к.  это  просто  слово-паразит.  К  примеру  Давыдов  из  "Поднятой  целины"  пользовался  словом  "факт".  Это  плеоназм,  а  не  эффемизм.  А  вот  "мля"  вместо  "бля"  это  тоже  не  эффемизм,  а  просто  новоявленное  интернетовское  хамство - вот  и  банят.  Если  в  самом  деле  банят,  конечно.

Comment: Я сужу по описанию в википедии - ссылку уже кидал. А она (википедия) говорит как раз что эти два слова являются эвфемизмами, причем родственных слов.

Если есть ссылка на более авторитетный ресурс с другими данными - то есть отличная возможность внести свой вклад в развитие википедии) Чтобы другие пользователи не ошибались (если это действительно так)

Comment: Наберите  эти  слова: эффемизм,  плеоназм  в  поисковой  строке, появятся  и  другие  источники.  Но  и  самому  подумать  можно.  Любители  поматериться  в  интернете  пытаются  так  обмануть  робота-модератора.  Человека-то  не  обманешь.

Comment: И вообще: зачем он нужен, мат? Что он даёт говорящему и слушающему? Зачем его надо прятать под эвфемизмами? Прячут обычно что-то ворованное или неприличное. До введения в обиход набедренных повязок ходили нагишом. Но это - когда было?!. Если бы мы не знали мата, как человек, которому на ногу упал кусок тяжёлой трубы, выразил бы свою боль, возмущение и проч.? Конечно, как-то прилично, общепринятыми словами. Давайте откажемся от мата! Он не спасает от боли, не несёт никакую смысловую нагрузку. Мат - это набор пустых слов, не несущих никакой информации. Зачем он нужен?! Гнать мат из нашей речи!!

Comment: В современной русской речи "ебальник" всё чаще уступает место слову "ебало". 

Из песни Растеряева: "тупое ебало, хуйню несу я"

Из детского стишка: "я серый волк, ебалом щёлк"

Наряду с этим, часто используется усиленная версия "еблище".